# ListView with BaseLayout shows only the first item

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I'm trying to create a BaseAdapter and to set it as a an adapter for ListView.

each element contains a button and a text in the Adapter.

this is my Ingredients Adapter that extends BaseAdapter:

```
package com.tuxin.myalcoholist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class IngredientsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();

private final Context context;

public List<String> getItems() {
    return this.ingredients;
}

public void add(final String value) {
    ingredients.add(value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public IngredientsAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}

public void updateIngredients(List<String> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients=ingredients;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.ingredients.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return ingredients.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.ingredient_item,parent,false);
    }
    Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_button);
    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_textView);
    final String ingredient = this.getItem(position);
    textView.setText(ingredient);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

first of all... am I implementing BaseAdapter properly?
I included the functions getItems() and add() because i had no idea how to fetch the items and add items otherwise.

what am I seeing only the first row ?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

this is my ingredient_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="del"
    android:id="@+id/ingredient_button"
   />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ingredient_textView"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
```

## update

client code that uses the adapter

```
    addIngredientButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String ingredient = ingredientEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ingredient)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"ingredient is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                  ingredientsAdapter.add(ingredient);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show us your `ingredient_item.xml` file. Also make sure you have a button with the id `ingredient_button` on that file.

Comment: updated main post. thanks

Comment: Make sure your `context` is not null. How are you initializing the adapter?

Comment: IngredientsAdapter ingredientsAdapter = new IngredientsAdapter(this.getActivity());

Comment: oops.. updating main post

Comment: now facing a different problem, updated the question

Comment: I tested your Adapter and I see no error in here. I get multiple content displayed. Not only first row. Are your sure your list contains more than one objecT? Show us how are you populating your list

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same `ingredientsAdapter` as the one you set to your listview? Because there is nothing wrong with your code so far.

Comment: Show your layout for ListView. May be you forget wrap_content for ListView's layout_height?

Comment: I guess the problem is on your `ingredient_item.xml`. Your row should wrap it's content. Change the `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content`

Comment: setting layout_height to wrap_content both in ingredient_item.xml and in the ListView but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually set the adapter on the listview?